# Order Statistics Notation

Tags: statistics, notation, random-variables, dice, order-statistics

According to Wikipedia...

> For example, suppose that four numbers are observed or recorded resulting in a sample of size $4$. If the sample values are $6, 9, 3, 8$, the order statistics would be denoted $x_{(1)} = 3,\ \ x_{(2)} = 6,\ \ x_{(3)} = 8, x_{(4)} = 9$, where the subscript $(i)$ enclosed in parentheses indicates the $i$th order statistic of the sample.
>
> The first order statistic (or smallest order statistic) is always the minimum of the sample, that is, $X_{(1)} = \min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$, where, following a common convention, we use upper-case letters to refer to random variables, and lower-case letters (as above) to refer to their actual observed values.

How is the transition made from $x_1$ to $X_1$?  Ordering observed values $x_1, ..., x_n$ (i.e., the specific rolls of identically distributed or non-identically distributed dice) makes sense, but ordering random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$, (i.e., the dice themselves) should consist of stipulating a meaning to the notion of ordering the probability distributions associated with a collection of non-identically distributed random variables; as a programmer must stipulate what member variable or function thereof constitutes the order metric for a user defined class, one would choose between mean, median, or any other real-valued statistic of the random variable to be used for its ordering.

Why are random variables used in order statistics seemingly for the role that observed values should play?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Given a list sample with $n$ elements, $X_1$ denotes the minimum.  That seems unambiguous, no?  It is, of course, a random variable.  Subsequent values may be ambiguous if ties are possible, I suppose...but is that what you were getting at?

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity between the random variable and observations of it. That situation seems entirely typical.  I could, for instance, let $Y$ denote the random variable giving me the face shown in the toss of an ordinary $6$ sided die.  In any actual toss, of course, $Y$ is a value.  But it makes sense to consider the random value without any observations of it.

Comment: @lulu When you say, "in any actual toss, of course, $Y$ is a value," shouldn't that be $y$ instead?  My understanding is that the result of an actual toss is not a random variable, but an observed value.  Wikipedia uses both concepts, and both capital and lowercase $x$ in its description, so it doesn't appear to be mere notational sloppiness.

Comment: I, personally, would not distinguish notationally between a random variable and an observation of it.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is that the random variable $X_{(i)}$ is defined as having a distribution corresponding to the $i$th smallest value in a set of $n$ iid samples.

You can't do the ordering until you have the actual sample values, but you *can* describe the distribution of values that the $i$th smallest sample will take.

Below is from the introduction of "Order Statistics and Inference" by Balakrishnan and Cohen. They are clear to make a distinction between the random variables and the values of the order statistics (note the non-standard notation), but it still corresponds with what's on Wikipedia.

[image]